# PostgreSQL compare string setting

Tags: postgresql, text, compare

I have one query, which returns different results on different servers.

```
select ' s' > '.'
```

First server return true, second - false.
What the are the settings that can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DBs have different [COLLATION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/collation.html):

> **The collation feature allows specifying the sort order** and character classification behavior of data per-column, or even per-operation. This alleviates the restriction that the LC_COLLATE and LC_CTYPE settings of a database cannot be changed after its creation.

```
select name, setting
from pg_settings
where name in ('lc_collate', 'server_encoding', 'client_encoding');

-- explicit collation
select ' s' COLLATE "POSIX" > '.' COLLATE "POSIX"
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/19255)**